# install and use GCC in windows 7 x64

Tags: gcc, gcc4.8

I am new to GCC, don't know much about it. I want to install it on my Windows 7 64bit PC and use it for C, C++ and Java. The latest version is GCC-4.8.0. In their mirror links, I am getting option to download ***gcc 4.8.0.tar.bz2*** and ***gcc 4.8.0.tar.gz*** and ***md5.sum***. Please guide me, how should i proceed, to use GCC

Comment: It looks like you're downloading the compiler's source code. I'd start here instead: http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Getting_Started

Comment: @Gabe can MinGW be upgraded to compile java code. As the installer does not show the option of Java Compiler.

Answer (score 4):

On Windows, easiest way to get `gcc` is to install [`MinGW`](http://www.mingw.org/).

Most recent MinGW release [has support for gcc 4.8](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/files/host-windows/releases/4.8.0/64-bit/threads-win32/seh) as well - but it may be not very stable at the moment.

Comment: [MinGW-64](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/) supports much more things compared to MinGW

Answer (score 1):

These files are *source archive files* of the latest released GCC compiler.

As a newbie, you probably want a binary distribution, e.g. [mingw](http://www.mingw.org/) or [cygwin](http://sourceware.org/cygwin/) on Windows. (Then you might get an earlier version of GCC. 4.8 has just been released)

Alternatively, consider switching to Linux and install it on your machine. It will teach you a big lot (and almost all of Linux is free software so you can get its source code and study it).

Using Linux and GCC also gives you a significant advantage: you could use *GCC plugins*, e.g. develop your own [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) extension (MELT is a domain specific language to extend GCC, implemented as a [meta-]plugin). Neither Mingw nor Cygwin support GCC plugins.

PS. compiling GCC from source code is not easy for a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

this is an older question but this was harder to search for than it should have been so I will post it here, http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/WindowsBuilding is a quick guide to getting gcc4.8 running on windows. I am about to dive in to building it on my old windows-xp box. wish me luck.

Answer (score 0):

I use codeblocks . You can follow this Youtube video for instructions:). Hope it helps!

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nNeySMSW8qU

Answer (score 0):

You should really check out Code::Blocks (http://codeblocks.org/).
It's a good IDE which is easily set up to get you started.

To support Windows 64-bit though you should not use the MinGW compiler that comes with it. Instead get a separate binary of MinGW-w64 with 64-bit support.
You can get it from http://winlibs.com where you can also find tips on how to configure both Windows 32-bit and 64-bit compilers.